# Error in huge R package when criterion "stars"

Tags: r

I am trying to do an association network using some expression data I have, the data is really huge: 300 samples and ~30,000 genes. I would like to apply a Gaussian graphical model to my data using the `huge` R package.

Here is the code I am using

```
dim(data)
#[1] 317 32291

huge.out <- huge.npn(data)
huge.stars <- huge.select(huge.out, criterion="stars")
```

However in this last step I got an error:

```
Error in cor(x) : ling....in progress:10% 
Missing values present in input variable 'x'. Consider using use = 'pairwise.complete.obs'
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The error seems very clear: you have missing values and it doesn't like it. What do you need help with?

Comment: I would have guessed that it was the `huge.npn` function call that threw the error since it is the one that calculates correlation coefficients. Should be possible to test the behavior of eitehr of htese functions with a much smaller example.

Comment: @Gregor, my data has not missing values, I double checked. I agree with BondedDust the error is related to correlation coefficients. The function worked very well in a subset of my data, but I would like to apply it to my whole data

Comment: @user2380782 your error says you have missing data, you say that you don't - without seeing a reproducible example we cannot help since we don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You posted this exact question on Rhelp today. Both SO and Rhelp deprecate cross-posting but if you do choose to switch venues it is at the very least courteous to inform the readership.

You responded to the suggestion here on SO that there were missing data in your data-object named 'data' by claiming there were no missing data. So what does this code return:

```
lapply(data , function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

That would be a first level check, but there could also be an error caused by a later step that encountered a missing value in the matrix of correlation coefficients in the matrix 'huge.out". That could happen if there were: a) infinities in the calculations or b) if one of the columns were constant:

```
> cor(c(1:10,Inf), 1:11)
[1] NaN
> cor(rep(2,7), rep(2,7))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In cor(rep(2, 7), rep(2, 7)) : the standard deviation is zero
```

So the next check is:

```
sum( is.na(huge.out) )
```

That will at least give you some basis for defending your claim of no missings and will also give you a plausible theory as to the source of the error. To locate a column that is entirely constant you might do something like this (assuming it were a dataframe):

```
 which(sapply(sapply(data, unique), length) > 1)
```

If it's a matrix, you need to use `apply`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BondedDust for the comments. First of all I won't repost anymore. Second, the results for the checks are: `lapply(data , function(x) sum(is.na(x)))` returns a list with all elements being 0, the second check is hard to apply because `huge.out` is an object with different values but I didn't find any `NA` value (although I think the problem is there). And the final check give me a vector with the same length as columns in data (32291). Thanks for the help and I will try to find out why the `huge.select` command does not works as I was expecting